# NSTextView line breaks triggered by action

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

I have a textField the accepts text input and prints to an NSTextView when pressing return. I need the action to insert a double line break each time the method is invoked. Basically I want to be able to build a list in the textView. How can I do this?

Thanks.

```
-(IBAction)printText:(id)sender;

{

NSString *theTextToOutput = [inputText stringValue];
NSString *clear = @"";


[outputText setString:theTextToOutput];


[inputText setStringValue:clear];




}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add line break in NSTextView writing **\n** like this:

```
NSString *stringWithLineBreak = @"test \n"
[outputText insertText:stringWithLineBreak];
```